# regular expression to escape html entities

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string that contains some html formatting tags. Using Regex.Replace() i would like to convert all text within the tags to character "x" but want to leave the tags as they are. The string is already escaping the tags.

Comment: show some sample data to make it more clear

Comment: You should [edit] your post and format your code. You can surround code in backticks ( ` ) or indent it by four spaces to make things like `<` show up properly. Or highlight it and click the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: You mean to say you replace each **non**-word character with `z` and you have HTML entities that get corrupted, right? If you have HTML tags inside, you will need to use a parser for that. Without input text and expected output, this question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understood your question, following code will solve your problem:

```
string str = @"Hi, how are you. hope you are doing good";
Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]", "z");
```

Output:

```
zz, zzz zzz zzz. zzzz zzz zzz zzzzz zzzz
```

If you don't want to replace numbers occuring in your word with `z` then remove `0-9`. If you want any other characters in words to replace with `z` include there. e.g., `[a-zA-Z\-]` will  include `-` in regex and replace this with `z` too. In Regex, note that to match  special characters, it should be preceded by `\`. e.g., to match `[`, it should be like `\[`.

Hope that will help.

**Update:**

I got you. Solution to your problem is:

```
string str = @"Hi, how are you. hope are you doing good &amp; &yen; whatis goind on &lessthan;and";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\b(?!&)[a-zA-Z]+(?!;)\b");

            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                string oldWord = m.ToString();
                str = Regex.Replace(str, oldWord, Regex.Replace(m.ToString(), @".", "z"));

            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

And, output is:

```
zz, zzz zzz zzz. zzzz zzz zzz zzzzz zzzz &amp; &yen; zzzzzz zzzzz zz &lessthan;zzz
```

Note:  *If you want to use HTML to convert/extract just some characters or pattern then it's fine.But, If you are planning to parse whole HTML using REGEX then don't even try to do so. Because HTML is Non-regular language. and REGEX doesn't have capability to parse HTML.*

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a plain text the text has html entities like Hi [ampersand]lessthan;  how are you strong[ampersand]greaterthan; and I would not like to replace these entities and whatever formatting they contain

Comment: Yep, I figured out that regex would not be the best idea, and hence leveraged an html parser for the same. Thank you for the regular expression.